# Capture multiple lightning:input values from a button click - LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have to capture multiple input values from a button click to pass in a wire method, I have tried the querySelector method and with that I couldn't able to achieve what I expect because of lack of knowledge.

I have tried like below, but didn't get anything for updatedCustomSetting.
HTML File

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Getting Started">
    <div>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <lightning-input type="text" 
                    label="Portfolio Label"
                    name="PortfolioName"
                    value={customSetting.Portfolio_Label__c}
                    maxlength="300" 
                    min="0">
        </lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <lightning-input type="checkbox"
                    label="Program Recursion" 
                    name="programRecursion"
                    value={customSetting.Program_Recursion__c}
                    checked={customSetting.Program_Recursion__c}>
        </lightning-input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Update" onclick={handleSettingUpdate} class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                            </lightning-button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS File

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getConfigSettings from '@salesforce/apex/LwcHierarchyConfigController.getConfigSettings';
import updateConfigSetting from '@salesforce/apex/LwcHierarchyConfigController.updateConfigSetting';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class HierarchyConfiguration extends LightningElement {

@track customSetting;
@track error;
@track isHide = false;

@track updatedCustomSetting = {};

@wire(getConfigSettings)
getSettings ({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        this.customSetting = data;
        this.error = undefined;
    } else if (error) {
        this.error = error;
        this.customSetting = undefined;
    }
}

// handleFormInputChange(event) {
//     this.updatedCustomSetting[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
// }

// handleFormInputCheckboxChange(event) {
//     this.updatedCustomSetting[event.target.name] = event.target.checked;
// }

handleSettingUpdate(event) {

    **In this place I have to capture the input value and build the updatedCustomSetting with key as lightning-input name and the value as the value. I would also like to do without onclick or onchange event in lightning-input**
    // this.updatedCustomSetting['PortfolioName'] = this.template.querySelector('PortfolioName').value;
    // this.updatedCustomSetting['PortfolioHierarchy'] = this.template.querySelector('PortfolioHierarchy').value;
    // this.updatedCustomSetting['portfolioRecursion'] = this.template.querySelector('portfolioRecursion').value;
    console.log('The setting is ::::' + this.updatedCustomSetting);       
    updateConfigSetting ({
        updatedCustomSetting: JSON.stringify(this.updatedCustomSetting)
    })
    .then(result => {
        if (result) {
            const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Record Updated Successfully',
                variant: 'success',
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.message = undefined;
        this.error = error;
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error in updating record',
                message: error.body.message,
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
    });
}
```

}

Will it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a changeHandler on all fields that will update the value on an Object that you can directly pass to `JSON.stringify();`

The object you already have `customSetting` we can use this one which you are using to store the data, which you are getting from Apex.

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    const name = event.target.name;
    let value = event.target.value;
    if (event.target.type === 'checkbox' || event.target.type === 'checkbox-button' || event.target.type === 'toggle') {
        value = event.target.checked;
    }

    this.customSetting = {
        ...this.customSetting,
        [name]: value
    };
}
```

Above code will update the property value `customSetting` provided in the name attribute of the `lightning-input` field.

You can add the change handler like this:

```
 <lightning-input type="text" 
      label="Portfolio Label"
      name="Portfolio_Label__c"
      value={customSetting.Portfolio_Label__c}
      maxlength="300" 
      min="0"
      onchange={handleChange}>
 </lightning-input>
```

Comment: +1 A small suggestion, as `customSetting` is already a tracked property you can also do `this.customSetting[name] = value;`. No need to clone it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have done the same as above and tried to do without the handleChange or handleClick in each input field. You can see the 1st comment under the handleSettingUpdate method. Actually I am trying to build a UI to update the custom setting as we cannot create a trigger on custom setting to do the consequence update on other object records. There is a limitation when building above object with individual on click function where it is not constructing the object with the key and value if we don’t change it. So my intention here is to build even if we don’t have the change.

Comment: This can be easily done using aura with the aura attribute with the custom setting as object type because aura is supporting two way binding. But I cannot see a direct binding in LWC for custom settings. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I have created a new property to create the object again from the input field change. When updating the same property with the above answer I could able to achieve my need. Thanks itzmukeshy7